# Google Sheets Script How can I save a null value to a data validation array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set data validation in a range of cells based on the values in another. For the most part it works. I push the relevant data validation rule for each target cell to a target array and then setDataValidations(target array) to the whole target range.

the problem is when I don't want a validation rule. What do I push to the array when I don't want validation in the target range?

Here is the relevant section of my code. In my code the case 'other page' should lead to no data validation being set, and that range contains only blanks, but this leads to a data validation rule which doesn't allow anything in the target cell.

```
    function allDataValidations()
{
var setupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Setup Data');
var urlArr = removeBlanksArray(setupSheet.getRange('b5:b').getValues());
Logger.log(urlArr);
var ParentPageDataValidationArray = [];
var arrayLength = urlArr.length
for (i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
  {
  switch (urlArr[i][0]) 
    {
    case 'index':
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dynamic').getRange('i2:i'); //set theme selection for index page, row 5

        break;
    case 'top category':
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dynamic').getRange('h2:h'); //set theme selection for index page, row 5       
        break;
    case 'sub category':
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dynamic').getRange('a2:a');
        break;
    case 'support article':
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dynamic').getRange('c2:c');
        break;    
    case 'other page':
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dynamic').getRange('z:z');
        break;         
    }
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireValueInRange(range).build();  
  if (range != null)
    {
  ParentPageDataValidationArray.push([rule]);  
    }
  else
    {
  ParentPageDataValidationArray.push([SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().build()]);
    }
  }
setupSheet.getRange('e5:e'+(arrayLength+4)).setDataValidations(ParentPageDataValidationArray)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing an empty string, just as a place holder in the ParentPageDataValidationArray array?

Comment: Yes, this also sets a rule excluding any entry.

Comment: How about pushing a second rule with has  .setAllowInvalid(true) ?

Comment: I feel I am missing something here; why have that case `other page` at all if you dont want it in the `allDataValidations()`?

Comment: Because I am pushing an array to speed things up. If I were to push the entries one by one it would be slow.

Comment: In any case I feel like an idiot because the answer is you need to push null into the array and it will not create a rule :) I thought I tried that already.

here is the code: ParentPageDataValidationArray.push([null]);